# Web Scraping Doordash

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to fill in the "Enter Address" search bar at https://www.doordash.com/en-US with the user input I get on pandas.

I have used the following code to find the field

```
html = browser.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
enter_address = soup.find('input', attrs={'class':'sc-jvjHmY kgyoRh'})
browser.fill(enter_address, Address)
```

This returns the following error:

```
ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with name "<input aria-label="Your delivery address" class="sc-jvjHmY kgyoRh" id="FieldWrapper-9" placeholder="Enter delivery address" type="text" value=""/>"
```

This is the block I see when I inspect on doordash.com

```
<input class="sc-jvjHmY kgyoRh" type="text" aria-label="Your delivery address" placeholder="Enter delivery address" id="FieldWrapper-17" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to wrong class name "sc-jvjHmY kgyoRh".
This class name is not fixed name, and generated by server.
So it is difficult to use that class name.
I think it is more proper to use id of input field or xpath.

Comment: Should I use 

enter_address = soup.browser.find_by_id('FieldWrapper-9')

Comment: If id is a constant, please try it. Some websites may change the id, so you should check the id.

Comment: the id is dynamic( changes every time the website renders). How can I use aria-label in this case?